# Taking complements of discriminated unions

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, typescript-types

Let's say I have the following discriminated unions and some associated types

```
type Union = 'a' | 'b';
type Product<A extends Union, B> = { f1: A, f2: B};
type ProductUnion = Product<'a', 0> | Product<'b', 1>;
```

Now I can take complements by using mapping types and `Exclude`

```
type UnionComplement = {
  [K in Union]: Exclude<Union, K>
};
// {a: "b"; b: "a"}

type UnionComplementComplement = {
  [K in Union]: Exclude<Union, Exclude<Union, K>>
};
// {a: "a"; b: "b"}
```

So far all of this makes sense but things break down for `ProductUnion` when I try to take the double complement. The first complement works fine

```
type ProductComplement = {
  [K in Union]: Exclude<ProductUnion, { f1: K }>
};
// {a: Product<'b', 1>; b: Product<'a', 0>}
```

The double complement is incorrect no matter what I try

```
type ProductComplementComplement = {
  [K in Union]: Exclude<ProductUnion, Exclude<ProductUnion, { f1: K }>>
};
// {a: ProductUnion; b: ProductUnion}
```

I don't understand where the bug is because if I substitute the types then it should work. There are only 2 values for `K` when taking the double complement so let's try the first one

```
type First = Exclude<ProductUnion, Exclude<ProductUnion, { f1: 'a' }>>;
// {f1: 'a'; f2: 0}
```

Second one also work

```
type Second = Exclude<ProductUnion, Exclude<ProductUnion, { f1: 'b' }>>;
// {f1: 'b'; f2: 1}
```

All the constituent parts work but when combined in the mapping type it seems to break down. What am I missing here?

On a whim I tried adding a type parameter to see what would happen by abstracting the complementing process

```
type Complementor<T> = {
    [K in Union]: Exclude<T, { f1: K }>
};

type DoubleComplementor<T> = {
    [K in Union]: Exclude<T, Exclude<T, { f1: K }>>
};
```

Now if I apply the parametrized types to `ProductUnion` it works exactly as I expect

```
type Complement = Complementor<ProductUnion>;
// {a: Product<'b', 1>; b: Product<'a', 0>}

type DoubleComplement = DoubleComplementor<ProductUnion>;
// {a: Product<'a', 0>; b: Product<'b', 0>}
```

Comment: This is very strange behavior, from what I can tell the compiler stops distributing over the `T` parameter for `Exclude` .. no idea why .. might be a bug.

Comment: Weird... I can't find any GitHub issues about nested distributive types failing to work like this.  It's as if the compiler simplifies something too aggressively before doing the distribution.  Might be worth filing an issue.

Comment: Thanks folks. I'll follow up by opening an issue later today.

Comment: So @TitianCernicova-Dragomir @jcalz what's the expected / the correct output here? the one of `ProductComplementComplement` or `DoubleComplement`

Comment: @AravindanVe the behavior OP expects is the one I would also expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed a bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28824. Thanks to Anders and team the next release should have more consistent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Abstracted type aliases are not supposed to act exactly the same way as inline ones do. I think that's the point.</s>

**EDIT**:

Okay, it does looks like a bug.

```
type E1 = Exclude<{ f1: 'a' } | { f1: 'b' },
            Exclude<{ f1: 'a' } | { f1: 'b' }, { f1: 'a' }>>;

// E1 = { f1: "a" }

type E2<K> = Exclude<{ f1: 'a' } | { f1: 'b' },
               Exclude<{ f1: 'a' } | { f1: 'b' }, { f1: K }>>;

// E2<K> = { f1: "a" } | { f1: "b" }
//         ^ no `K` in the resulting type
//         the compiler has somehow eliminated `K` from the resulting type

// no matter what you do from here on, doesn't get re-evaluated with K in it.
//
type E2a = E2<'a'>;
// E2a = { f1: "a" } | { f1: "b" }

type E2b = E2<'b'>;
// E2b = { f1: "a" } | { f1: "b" }
```

Comment: Are you aware of [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types)? The difference between "abstracted" and "inlined" type alias logic should be that when the conditional type is acting on a bare type parameter name it will distribute the conditional type over a union, whereas it won't otherwise. This is expected.  What we are not expecting is for `Exclude<>` to suddenly stop distributing when used in a nested way. As @TitianCernicova-Dragomir said in a comment, this might be a compiler bug.

Comment: Okay I did not know about this!

Comment: @jcalz thanks! I somehow missed the whole section on __distributive conditional types__.